# Why do I get the error "'function' object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python

This is my code block

```
import json
import difflib
from difflib import get_close_matches

definitions = json.load(open("data.json"))

def thesaurus(words):
    if words in definitions:
        return definitions[words]
    elif len(get_close_matches(words, definitions.keys())) > 0:
        yn = input("Did you mean %s instead? Enter 'Y' if yes or 'N' if no: " % get_close_matches(words,definitions.keys()) [0])
        if yn == "Y":
            return thesaurus[get_close_matches(words, definitions.keys())]
        elif yn == "N":
            return "None found"
    else:
        return "Please check word again"


words = input("Look Up: ").lower()

print(thesaurus(words))
```

I expected to receive the meaning of the word "Grief". However, I kept receiving the error : function object is not subscriptable.

Here is the terminal log, just in case it might help:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:Python Adwok$ python3 dictionary.py
Look Up: GRERFAG
Did you mean grief instead? Enter 'Y' if yes or 'N' if no: Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dictionary.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(thesaurus(words))
  File "dictionary.py", line 13, in thesaurus
    return thesaurus[get_close_matches(words, definitions.keys())]
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Please point out even the smallest details, I would appreciate that very much.

Comment: Because you are subscripting a function object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the error stack, in line 13 you are accessing `thesaurus` as if it was a list/dictionary (or any subscriptable object). Since `thesaurus` is a function (which is not subscriptable), you get an error. Thus, you need to invoke the function (instead of accessing it):

```
thesaurus(get_close_matches(words, definitions.keys()))
```

Also, you should notice:

- At the end of your code you are correctly invoking the `thesaurus` function by calling `print(thesaurus(words))`
- Consider reusing the result of `get_close_matches` to avoid multiple calls to the same function (which can lead to performance degradation if the call is resource consuming).

I suggest you the following solution:

```
import json
import difflib
from difflib import get_close_matches

definitions = json.load(open("data.json"))

def thesaurus(words):
    if words in definitions:
        return definitions[words]
    else:
        close_matches = get_close_matches(words, definitions.keys())
        if len(close_matches) > 0:
            yn = input("Did you mean %s instead? Enter 'Y' if yes or 'N' if no: " % get_close_matches(words,definitions.keys()) [0])
            if yn == "Y":
                return thesaurus(close_matches)
            elif yn == "N":
                return "None found"
        else:
            return "Please check word again"


words = input("Look Up: ").lower()

print(thesaurus(words))
```